# The probability of having $k$ successes before $r$ failures in a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, random-variables

**Problem**

Find the probability of having $k$ successes before $r$ failures in a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with $p$ being the probability of success.

I thought of using the Binomial distribution, the random variable $X$ is the number of successes, only this time I am interested not only in the number of successes but also in which order they are obtained. If the number of trials was $n$, then obviously I suppose $r+k \leq n$, I don't quite get the problem: the $k$ successes have to be one after the other, I mean, have to be $k$ successive successes?. I would like some explanation on the problem and suggestions of how could I calculate the probability I am being asked.

Comment: My interpretation of the event the probability of which you are asked to find is: the $k$th success comes before the $r$th failure. They don't have to be consecutive: some failures may be mixed in. One approach (not necessarily best) is to introduce $t$, the number of trial that delivers the $k$th success, and observe that you are looking for probabilities of exactly $k$ successes in $t$ trials, summed over $t=k,\dots,k+r-1$.

Comment: This doesn't use measure theory, as required from [tag:probability-theory], thus removed. Same for [tag:probability-distributions]; it is a question about the probability of a specific event.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the **negative binomial distribution**?

Comment: Imagine that you perform $k+r-1$ trials, even if the outcome ($k$ successes or $r$ failures) was already known earlier. Then the event "$k$ successes before $r$ failures" is the same (I mean exactly the same event, not just the same probability) as "at least $k$ successes in $k+r-1$ trials".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Interpretation A**

> What is the probability of observing $k$ consecutive successes followed by $r$ consecutive failures?

It's a rather simple solution:
The probability of succeeding is $p$, thus succeeding $k$ times independently has probability $p^k$. Same for failing $r$ times independently: $(1-p)^r$.
In total we have
$$P = p^k (1-k)^r$$

---

**Interpretation B**

> What is the probability that exactly $k$ successes occur before the $r$-th failure?

We need to put these $k$ successes in order with $r-1$ failures and obtain an additional failure (the $r$-th) giving
$$P = \binom{k+r-1}k p^k (1-p)^{r-1} \cdot (1-p) = \binom{k+r-1}k p^k (1-p)^r$$

---

**Interpretation C**

> What is the probability that (at least) $k$ successes are observed before the $r$-th failure occurs?

This is requesting *at most* $r-1$ failures before $k$ successes (see @Thursdays comment). In this case we have
$$P = \sum_{j=0}^{r-1} \binom{k-1+j}{k-1} p^k (1-p)^j$$
as a solution

Thanks to @DilipSarvate for the interpretation titles
Thanks to @BrianMScott and @robjohn for spotting an error in the formula for interpretation C (after all this time)

Comment: This is also the probability that $r$ failures occur followed by $k$ successes, isn't it?

Comment: @DilipSarwate It's also the probability of any _specified_ order in wich $k$ successes and $r$ failures can occur. (for example alternating starting with a success if $k=r$)

Comment: @AlexR if we think the problem as Thursday suggested, then I think there is a combinatorial missing. After the $r-th$ failure I want to obtain $k$ successes, so shouldn't it be $\binom{k+r-1}{k}p^k(1-p)^r$?

Comment: @user100106 I am reading this as "first succeed $k$ times, then fail $r$ times" in wich case the combinatorial is not necessary. Feel free to clarify your exact question (i.e. elaborate on your wording)

Comment: Ok, I've understood the solution of the problem for both cases, so I am going to accept your answer. Providing the problem is as Thursday says, does my answer seem correct to you?

Comment: @user100106 As I said, if you elaborate the wording, we can work out an alternative solution. If you only want to ensure the last of the $r$ failures comes after $k$ sucesses, your formula is correct, since we need $k$ successes within $k+r-1$ trials and a final failure.

Comment: @user100106 I have included the alternative in the answer now.

Comment: Except the alternative answer is incorrect even under the alternative interpretation chosen which is _not_ the same as the one suggested by @Thursday. We need $k-1$ successes in the first $k+r-2$ trials and then the $k$th success occurs on the $(k+r-1)$-th trial. What happens on the $(k+r)$-th trial is irrelevant. If $k$ successes have _not_ occurred in $k+r-1$ trials, then at least $r$ failures must have occurred and the game is lost. The indices of $p$ and $(1-p)$ must sum to $k+r-1$, and not $k+r$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate this is a third possible interpretation (tbh I did not read all the comments) But yes, this is a _new_ interpretation giving another (distinct) solution. I am going to add this as well. I added a note on that as well. Do you agree?

Comment: Interpretation A is "What is the probability of observing $k$ consecutive successes followed by $r$ consecutive failures?" Incidentally, your answer has a typo in it. Interpretation B is "What is the probability that exactly $K$ successes occur before the $r$-th failure?" Interpretation C _should_ be "What is the probability that $k$ successes are observed before the $r$-th failure occurs?" and I don't agree with your answer to it. You need to find the sum of the probabilities that the $k$-th success occurs on $k$-th, $(k+1)$-th, $\ldots, (k+r-1)$-th trial.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes, that's correct. I'll alter it. Do you mind if I copy your Question titles into the answer?

Comment: @AlexR Feel free to use my suggested titles.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you. Can you confirm correctness of **C**? I altered the exponent of $(1-p)$.

Comment: @user100106: The answer for **Interpretation C** is wrong, I’m afraid; see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411830/probability-with-n-successes-before-m-failures/1411859?noredirect=1#comment2876438_1411859) and its accepted answer.

Comment: Taking the limit of the answer for **Interpretation C** as $r\to\infty$ gives $\frac1p$, which cannot be right.

Comment: @robjohn Sorry, but I can't see how the limit would be $\frac1p$. What's your $k$?

Comment: @AlexR: Any $k$: $$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{k+j}kp^k(1-p)^j
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{k+j}jp^k(1-p)^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{-k-1}jp^k(1-p)^j\\
&=p^k(1-(1-p))^{-k-1}\\
&=\frac1p
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @robjohn Thanks... I now see where the double counting occurs. I think taking the binomial term to be $$\binom{k-1+j}{k-1}$$ should fix it. This makes the limit equal to $1$, as expected

Comment: "after all this time" Indeed, in the sense that the error was already "spotted" by another user 11 months ago, even if you did not see fit to react to this signalment until 1 hour ago (why?).

Comment: @Did Probably the notification escaped me 11 months ago, who knows.

Comment: Let us hope there are not too many other signalments which somehow "escaped" you...

Comment: @Did Do you have anything special on your mind? I'm not that active anymore for various reasons, as you might have noticed.

Comment: Do you mean, did I scan your answers to find other forgotten comments objecting to them? No I did not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62770/discussion-between-alexr-and-did).

Comment: @Did If you like, we can chat about that since it's not really on-topic for the particular question at hand.

Comment: Would interpretation A require a scaling constant? As written, I think it's the probability of observing exactly $k$ successes in $k+r$ total trials, neglecting the order. Might be missing something though

Comment: @DavidM. Interpretation A is the probability of observing a specific path with $k$ successes and $r$ failures. Your description requires to count all such paths and thus multiply by the number of such paths, $\binom{k+r}k$.

Comment: @AlexR That’s right, I had it flipped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I take this to mean the probability of getting $k$ successes before the $r^\text{th}$ failure. To keep the cases separate, we case on the $k^\text{th}$ success.

---

The probability of $k-1$ successes and $j$ failures followed by a success is $\binom{k+j-1}{j}p^k(1-p)^j$. Thus, the probability of $k$ successes before $r$ failures is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\binom{k+j-1}{j}p^k(1-p)^j
$$

---

As it should be, the limit as $r\to\infty$ is $1$
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{k+j-1}{j}p^k(1-p)^j
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{-k}{j}p^k(1-p)^j\\
&=p^k(1-(1-p))^{-k}\\[12pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$