# Probability with $n$ successes before $m$ failures

Tags: probability

Independent trials resulting in a success with probability $p$ and a failure with probability
$1 − p$ are performed. What is the probability that $n$ successes occur before $m$
failures?

Given solution :

> $$P = \sum_{k=n}^{m+n-1} \binom{m+n-1}k p^k (1-p)^{m+n-1-k}$$

*Explanation given* : Fermat argued that, in order for $n$ successes to occur before $m$ failures, it is necessary
and sufficient that there be at least $n$ successes in the first $m + n − 1$ trials.
(Even if the game were to end before a total of $m + n − 1$ trials were completed, we
could still imagine that the necessary additional trials were performed.) This is true,
for if there are at least $n$ successes in the first $m + n − 1$ trials, there could be at
most $m − 1$ failures in those $m + n − 1$ trials; thus, $n$ successes would occur before
$m$ failures. If, however, there were fewer than n successes in the first $m + n − 1$
trials, there would have to be at least $m$ failures in that same number of trials; thus, $n$
successes would not occur before $m$ failures. Hence the probability is as above.

My solution :

> $$P = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+k}n p^n (1-p)^k$$

I consider all the possible permutations where the $n$ success occur before $m$ failures. I really can't see what's wrong here.
This is the same as interpretation C [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/915359/93949) and no interpretation of that answer matches the given solution.
So, how is the given solution correct in comparison to mine?

Comment: ? m=11;n=6;p=0.5;print(sum(k=0,m-1,binomial(n+k,n)*p^n*(1-p)^k))
1.667694091796875000000000000  is a small PARI/GP-program showing that the second formula cannot be correct, because the result is a probability greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events represented by the terms of your summation are not pairwise disjoint. Consider, for example, the outcome in which the first $n$ trials are successes; that situation is counted both in the $k=0$ term and in the $k=1$ term, since the latter includes the sequence of $n$ successes followed by $1$ failure.

We can also use the fact that

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n+k}nx^k=\frac1{(1-x)^{n+1}}$$

to observe that if $p=\frac12$, then

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n+k}np^n(1-p)^k=\frac1{2^n}\cdot\frac1{(1/2)^{n+1}}=2\;,$$

so your summation must be greater than $1$ for sufficiently large $m$; this doesn’t explain *why* it’s wrong, but it does show that it can’t be right.

Comment: The answer that I linked to, also made the same error.

Comment: @Atul: Thanks; I’ll leave a comment there with a pointer to this question.