# Comparison of different solutions to the problem of points

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have the following problem:

> Find the probability of having k successes before r failures in a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with p being the probability of success.

Now, this has been asked here before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/915353/855205), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1411830/855205), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2718188/855205)) and there's even a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points) discussing Pascal's and Fermat's solutions to a variation of the problem. My question is about how the different solutions available online compare. I've found the following,

#### Fermat's solution

The solution done by Fermat in which one assumes $k+r−1$ trials and considers the probability of having at least k succeses, that is:
$$P = \sum_{i=k}^{k+r-1} \binom{k+r-1}i p^i (1-p)^{k+r-1-i}$$
The reasoning for this is

> Fermat argued that, in order for k successes to occur before r failures, it is necessary and sufficient that there be at least k successes in the first k+r−1 trials. (Even if the game were to end before a total of k+r−1 trials were completed, we could still imagine that the necessary additional trials were performed.) This is true, for if there are at least k successes in the first k+r−1 trials, there could be at most r−1 failures in those k+r−1 trials; thus, k successes would occur before r failures. If, however, there were fewer than k successes in the first k+r−1 trials, there would have to be at least r failures in that same number of trials; thus, k successes would not occur before r failures. Hence the probability is as above.

The second kind of solution I found does not assume one can extend the number of trials to $k+r−1$

#### "Direct" solution

Considering the game ends when the $k$-th success is achieved, and looking only at the cases where there are at most $r-1$ failures, one gets
$$P = \sum_{j=0}^{r-1} \binom{k-1+j}{k-1} p^k (1-p)^j$$
Where each term of the sum represents the probability of having ended the game with exactly $k$ successes after $k+j$ trials. I have found different variations of this, where one counts failures instead of successes, but I believe they're essentially the same solution.

So my question is, are these two solutions equivalent and if so why? I have tried to show the two expressions match but couldn't do it. Particularly, I find the assumption one could extend the number of trials very reasonable and intuitive, but wouldn't know how to justify it rigorously, which makes me a bit uneasy.

Answer (score 1):

Define $B$ as the event in which we get $k$ successes before we get $r$ failures. Then we define $A_{i}$ as the event in which we get a total of $i$ successes if we continue until we have $k+r-1$ trials.

$$
\sum_{i}{P\left(A_{i}|B\right)}=P\left(B\right)
$$

The left hand side is the Fermat’s solution while the right one is your Direct solution.